# why would i have compile error when i'm using a STL map?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm using a variable `A` of type `map<string, int>` and a `string s` in my program below:

```
map<string, int> A;
A["X"] = 10;
string s = "LXX";
int ans += A[s[2]];
```

but when i run the code, compile error comes:

`no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>' and '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type {aka char}')`

a char in string like `s[2]` cannot be an index of a map? How should i use it correctly to get that(`A[s[2]]`)?

Comment: If you want our help with your problem, then you first should create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem. Then edit your question to include that example (with a comment on the line that causes the error), and the *complete* output of the compiler, including possible informational notes. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: missing some context from your program... but i presume you are getting the int mapped by the string, right? So just A[s] should get your int.

Comment: `s[i]` is a `char`, not a `std::string`, so you have a type mismatch.

Comment: I got it.Thx for helping me and im really sry cause im new here and didn't ask a question using the right way.I'll do my best to learn english and how to ask good questions.thank u again

Comment: I've edit my question to be more complete. But it's such a primary question due to my careless.Very sry for asking questions like this, and i'll be more careful next time to ask some really valuable questions which i cant solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `[]` operator on string, you are getting an `char` right?

Key of your map is `std::string` while you are passing an `char` which arent compatible.

What you have to do is pass an valid key -> `std::string` to get mapped `int`.

```
map<string, int> m;
std::string s("test");

m[s] = 10;

if ( m.find(s) == m.end() )
{
  // not found
} else
{
  // found
}
```

---

If you would like to map characters of your `std::string` you have to change declaration of your map to `std::map<char, int>` or pass an strings with 2 characters. (one is null terminating character)

```
A[std::string(s[i])]   ---> 'c' to "c\0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are mapping characters from the `string` to an `int`, try changing the `map<string, int>` to `map<char, int>`. If you are mapping `string` to `int`, try accessing with `A[s]`.